# Intellij IDEA: NoClassDefError in Instrumentation test of a SherlockActivity, but working from Maven commandline

Tags: android, intellij-idea, actionbarsherlock, android-testing

I'm trying to setup an instrumentation test for an `Activity` which extends `SherlockActivity`, it compiles (and runs) but fails with `NoClassDefError` exception:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Exception in constructor: testPreconditions     (java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.dgti.ds.activities.ChooseLocationActivity
at com.dgti.ds.test.activities.ChooseLocationActivityTest.<init>(ChooseLocationActivityTest.java:11)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:415)
at junit.runner.BaseTestRunner.getTest(BaseTestRunner.java:103)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.getTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:127)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.setTestClassName(AndroidTestRunner.java:55)
at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.addTestClassByName(TestSuiteBuilder.java:81)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClass(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:418)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.parseTestClasses(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:399)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:364)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3246)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2200(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:969)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

I'm using Maven and got `ActionBarSherlock` as a dependency in the test project's pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.actionbarsherlock</groupId>
  <artifactId>actionbarsherlock</artifactId>
  <version>4.2.0</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
  <type>apklib</type>
</dependency>
```

this the test case:

```
public class ChooseLocationActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ChooseLocationActivity> {

    public ChooseLocationActivityTest() {
        this(ChooseLocationActivity.class);
    }

    public ChooseLocationActivityTest(Class<ChooseLocationActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    public void setUp() throws Exception {

    }

    public void tearDown() throws Exception {

    }

    public void testPreconditions() throws Exception {

    }
}
```

its worth mentioning that I can successfully run other tests and also this one if I change the activity to a non-Sherlock activity.

**also, building and running the test project from maven command line works and the tests are running on the emulator and passing !**

how can I fix this ?

Answer (score 4):

apparently the problem was with the ActioBarSherlock dependency marked as 'compile' in the test project's dependencies list. (in pom.xml its set to 'provided')

changing it to 'provided' fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you! I've spent a couple of hours trying to debug a similar problem and your answer saved my day :)